# Term for referring to someone with mediocre words to describe their greatness

Tags: phrases, expressions, phrase-meaning

What is the term for describing the following sort of phrases used to humoristically, and almost affectionately, describe someone who is obviously well known to be superb in their field?

> Referring to a famous accomplished sports star: I guess you could say
>   he's pretty good at throwing a ball.
>
> Referring to a supermodel: Yeah, she's not too hard on the eyes.
>
> Referring to a genius moviemaker: He's got some skills at spinning a
>   tale.

These, as opposed to saying something straightforward such as:

> Referring to a famous accomplished sports star: He's an amazing
>   athlete and throws like no other.
>
> Referring to a supermodel: Her beauty is unmatched in the world of
>   modeling.
>
> Referring to a genius moviemaker: The movies he's produced set the
>   standard in the industry.

Comment: Closely related question: [Literary term for an obvious understatement to emphasize excess](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/84641/literary-term-for-an-obvious-understatement-to-emphasize-excess/84646#84646).

Comment: [Meiosis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meiosis_(figure_of_speech)). Your second one is [litotes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Litotes).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might be looking for the word **understatement**.  According to Merriam-Webster:

> Understate(v):  to state or present with restraint especially for effect

The "effect" in this case is often humorous.

Answer (score 1):

What is the nature of the understating?

Is it intended as irony, in order to stress the greatness?

Or is it simply to diminish the person. If it is the latter there is a well-known idiom ***damning [someone] with faint praise***.

Comment: In this case, I'm referring to an inverse usage to convey positive feelings such as humor and/or appeal.

Comment: @eComEvo Well - that is *irony*. You are referring to them ***with irony***.

Comment: Sorry, I should not have said "inverse" since it is not quite to the level of irony I'm looking for.